Why doesn't PyCharm stop tests while running?
I have a pytest 8.3.4 testsuite running on an updated Windows 11 machine on Python 3.11.9 executed by PyCharm Community Edition 2024.3 as my team mates have.
What is happening for me, is not happening for them: if I start a test execution, and then I want to stop using the big red stop button, nothing happens; test keep going until the end.

I have used the same for years without a problem. I have uninstalled reinstalled, I also have changed my laptop, arriving in the same situation.
I'm afraid that could be related with "Beyondtrust privilege management" software (my company has installed that on some computer as mine) that maybe is not giving permissions to stop the threads, but generally it raises an exception if something is required.
Any suggestions?

Have you asked the JetBrains support?

No. Anyway I have understood that everything is working normally if I run PyCharm as administrator. I'm gonna send an email to JetBrains support, but I already know they will respond "Ask to your IT department" and my IT department is gonna reply "We have done nothing".

But that's not a programming question. If you want to ask experts in this field, ask on Super User

Ok I'm sorry, I didn't know. Should I delete this post?

I don't know. Currently, there are no downvotes or close votes. Maybe someone has a a solution for this problem.
